Humorous remarks in Questions
Someone, (totally not me,) posted a question, peppered with a humorous remark.
Is it ok to be using humor in Questions, if it does not distract from the point of the question itself?

Not sure we need 2 separate questions for this.  I'm going to merge this with: https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2429/7001
